# rxjs and angular 2 and the use of the "take" operator

Tags: angular, rxjs5

I am trying to use the "take" operator in my code (learning rxjs) but it is not sending the top 5 like I want.  my simple code is below, anyone have any idea how to help?

```
countries: Observable<Country[]>;

private searchTerms = new Subject<string>();

this.countries = this.searchTerms.debounceTime(300).distinctUntilChanged().switchMap(  
            searchTerm => searchTerm ? this.countrySearchService.search(searchTerm) : observable.of<Country[]>([])) 
            .take(5);
```

Comment: why take(5) and not take(1)? Are you trying to get the last 5 results or the last 5 contries in the array?

Comment: I would like to take the first 5 countries in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading your comment, I understand you need the first 5 countries. Now note that your observable emits arrays of countries and not countries. The reason you use Observable.of instead of Observable.from. So, the right syntax should be:

```
this.countries = this.searchTerms.debounceTime(300).distinctUntilChanged().switchMap(  
        searchTerm => searchTerm ? this.countrySearchService.search(searchTerm) : observable.from<Country[]>([])) 
        .take(5);
```

If you want a sample that demonstrate various use cases, have a look at [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/jusuzep/edit?js,console).